# How to run/deploy vue-cli server with webpack?

Tags: node.js, web, webpack, vue.js

I made project with vue-cli(node.js+vue.js), now i need to deploy it. How to run server with already installed and configured(by vue-cli) webpack? What should i do?

UPD: I want to deploy a whole server, not only static js. Because i have back-end with API and some stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idk what template you used, but most provide a `npm build` command. Just make sure you didn't set anything only for development  that you need in production.

Comment: I built project by webpack, but there are only 3 static js file(and index.html with ccs.js). What should i do with them?  And also i use my back-end for API, I mean, I need my back-end in webpack too.

Comment: @ramazan793 ccs.js? do you mean css and js? Anyways just put you files on your server and configure your routing (where you're probably fine with the standard if you only have index.html)

Comment: As i understand, webpack is only compressing front-end, is it? But what about back-end? Should I deploy raw back-end on the hosting ? Then i have full website with back-end and front-end, with structure like: raw back-end + dist folder?